# how to use Slidables as widget without the child being a ListTile in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I make this Slidable widget work, I'm mapping through a list and I want each of them to have a Slidable widget, so I can access the features of the Slidable package.

```
children: store.alarmList
                      .map((e) => Alarms(
                            hours: e.getHour,
                            mins: e.getMin,
                            isWednesday: e.wednesday,
                            isMonday: e.monday,
                            isSunday: e.sunday,
                            isTuesday: e.tuesday,
                            isThursday: e.thursday,
                            isFriday: e.friday,
                            isAlarmOn: e.alarmOn,
                            handleAlarmOn: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                e.alarmOn = value;
                                print(e.alarmOn);
                              });
                            },
                            isSaturday: e.saturday,
                            alarmRing: e.getAlarmRing,
                            snooze: e.getSnooze,
                            vibrate: e.getVibrate,
                          ))
                      .toList()
```

Comment: I didn't understand: do you want a slidable for every value of the map? Also, maybe a larger example of the code could be useful

Comment: I found a way to make it work, turns out I didn't install the dependency correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
children: store.alarmList
                      .map((e) => Slidable(
                            child: Alarms(
                            hours: e.getHour,
                            mins: e.getMin,
                            isWednesday: e.wednesday,
                            isMonday: e.monday,
                            isSunday: e.sunday,
                            isTuesday: e.tuesday,
                            isThursday: e.thursday,
                            isFriday: e.friday,
                            isAlarmOn: e.alarmOn,
                            handleAlarmOn: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                e.alarmOn = value;
                                print(e.alarmOn);
                              });
                            },
                            isSaturday: e.saturday,
                            alarmRing: e.getAlarmRing,
                            snooze: e.getSnooze,
                            vibrate: e.getVibrate,
                          )))
                      .toList()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?